# Chrome automation extension has crashed while using RSelenium

Tags: r, google-chrome, rselenium

I'm trying to use RSelenium package as follows:

```
 library(RSelenium)
 
 url    <- "https://www.google.com.mx/"
 
 driver <- RSelenium::rsDriver()
```

But even if chrome opens I got this:

[image]

```
Chrome automation extension has crashed. click this balloon to reload the extension
```